# Playing Vimeo video in mobile devices using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, vimeo

I am working on a project where i have to play the Vimeo video and i preffer to use the [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto) library.

The Problem arrises when i open the Vimeo Video then it generates error "Error Loading Page" and After that Video plays smoothly without any error. I want to Cater this situation.

I investigate that it is because of Jquery(version 1.6.2) reference and Jquerymobile reference.

Any Help? I am Stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my solution does: via jQuery, it detects mobile devices, and replaces the embedded Vimeo video player by the appropriate link to the Vimeo website for mobile phones.

**1 - Detect mobile**

I just downloaded a jQuery script from Detect Mobile Browsers (dotcom), and added it to my website, just after loading jQuery.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="[path]/detectmobilebrowser.js"></script>
```

This script will create a new property, `jQuery.browser.mobile`, which will be true if the browser is a mobile device.

**2 - Replace all Vimeo iFrames by appropiate links to Vimeo for Mobile, pointing to the right video.**

This is the code. Just put it inside jQuery’s ready function and you’re done. You can also put it inside a function and fire the function whenever you need it if you prefer.

```
if (jQuery.browser.mobile == true) {
$('iframe').each(function() {
if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf('http://player.vimeo.com') != -1) {
var videoiFrame;
videoiFrame = {
height : $(this).height(),
width: $(this).width(),
src : $(this).attr('src')
}
// Find video code
var videoCode = videoiFrame.src.split('?');
videoCode = videoCode[0];
videoCode = videoCode.split('/');
videoCode = videoCode[(videoCode.length -1)];
// videoCode found, now replace iFrame
$(this).before('<a class="mobile-video"
  style="width: '+ videoiFrame.width +'px ; height: '+ videoiFrame.height+'px;
    line-height: '+ videoiFrame.height+'px;"
  href="http://www.vimeo.com/m/'+ videoCode + '"></a>');
$(this).remove();
}
});
}
```

And that’s it. Tested successfully on Nokia Lumia 800 (which has no Flash, just like iphone)